# What is the starting point for a WCF Library app?

Tags: wcf

Where is the best place to put code for when a WCF service is just started up?  Similar to Page_Load in a web application.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The service implementation constructor would be the obvious place but it also depends on your hosting model

1) run once code: IIS hosting = global.asax; self-hosting = Main / OnStart

2) run once per service instance: constructor of service class

3) Something more exotic: implement [IInstanceProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iinstanceprovider.aspx)

Comment: This was a better answer than mine!

Answer (score 1):

In the class constructor of the service implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly the best place is the constructor and/or static constructor for your service class (for static members). There is no other WCF specific lifecycle event that will notify your service implementation when it's being created by the service host.

Now, if you're talking about the creation of services generically, that would mean you're willing to hook into the WCF runtime and there you can do things like get in the middle of the instance creation with a custom [`IInstanceProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iinstanceprovider.aspx) implementation.